# Download of ftp-file and transfer to PHP standard output not working correctly

Tags: php, ftp, video-streaming, html5-video

I have **.mp4 video files** on a server, the only access to these files is **FTP** (or WebDAV). The files are typically < 100 MB. To use these videos in a webpage, I targetted to build a **PHP script** that reads the video file via FTP and outputs the content to the standard output. Something like this:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect( $FTPaccount['server'] );
ftp_login( $ftp, $FTPaccount['user'], $FTPaccount['pass'] );
ftp_set_option( $ftp, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false );
ftp_pasv( $ftp, true );
$fout = fopen( 'php://output', 'w+' );
ftp_fget( $ftp, $fout, $filepath, FTP_BINARY, 0 );
fclose( $fout );
ftp_close( $ftp );
```

Roughly this works, but with the following disadvantages:

- looking into the devtools (Network), I see request is in status pending forever
- loading time is quite long (30s for 20 MB)
- for comparision: when I map the ftp-server in Windows Explorer as WebDAV and open a video file with chrome it takes 1s
- when the transfer looks complete, the video can be started and stopped but it's **not possible to position** within the video on the timeline, which is a severe restriction for any usage

All this strange behaviour may have to do with the handling of video streams between server and browser, also with buffering. I tested several variants including

```
stream_set_write_buffer( $fout, 0 );
flush();
```

or

```
$url = 'ftp://' . $FTPaccount['user'] . ':' . urlescape( $FTPaccount['pass'] ) . '@' . $FTPaccount['server'] . '/' . $filepath;
$ctx = stream_context_create();
@readfile( $url, false, $ctx );
```

but no improvement.

So I appreciate any help or suggestion how and where to look deeper

Comment: Another issue with your approach is that you hand out your login credentials to everyone interested on the internet.